# Calling string or in within if or try from outside

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'd like some help with something please.

Theres probably some incredibly easy solution to this but when I try to declare a value within if or try tags, and i try to call them from outside, I just get the error 'the name 'x' does not exist in the current context'

Any suggestions? Here's an example of what i mean

```
try {
    bleh = 5; }

x = bleh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variables outside your try blocks. Declaring a variable allows you to assign it, but it is only accessible within [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). This is a fundamental concept in programming languages and should should read the article linked above.

```
int bleh;
if (somevalue == 0)
{
bleh = 5;
}
else if (somevalue == 1)
{
bleh = 2;
}

x = bleh
```

Comment: That's the problem, it needs to be inside them, probably shoulda used if as example but, let's just say that if somevalue is 0 then i want x to do a different calculation then if somevalue is 1.   EDIT: I know what you mean ^^ thanks

Answer (score 1):

Declare it outside the if/try.

```
int bleh;
try
{
    bleh = 5;
}

x = bleh
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your variables *outside* that scope block:

```
int blah;

if (somevalue == 0)
{
  bleh = 5;
}
else if (somevalue == 1)
{
  bleh = 2;
}

x = bleh
```

In your code, the variable `bleh` is only available within that `try { }` area.  This is true for `if {}`, `switch {}`, `using {}`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared variable inside the block of try/if. So, the scope of variable ends when "}" line  is executed. You need to do something like this:

```
int bleh = 0;
try
{
   bleh = 5;
}catch(Exception ex){}

x = bleh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int bleh = 0;
try
{
   bleh = 5;
}
x = bleh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int bleh=0;
try
{
    bleh = 5;
}

x = bleh
```